# Telerik Kendo grid unable to get control value

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am unable to get edited control value from telerik jquery grid row. I am using .net core telerik kendo grid

> @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.LedgerEntries)
> .Name("LedgerEntries")
> .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Add New Voucher Row"))
> .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
> .Columns(columns =>
> {
> columns.Bound(p => p.ACCNT_CODE).Title("Account Code").ClientTemplate("#= ACCNT_CODE #" +
> "");
>
> columns.Bound(p => p.TRANS_AMT).Title("Debit").HtmlAttributes(new {
> @id = "TRANS_AMT" }).ClientTemplate("#= TRANS_AMT #" + "");
>
> ```
>                      columns.Bound(p => p.TRANS_AMT).Title("Credit").ClientTemplate("#= TRANS_AMT_1 #" +
> ```
>
> "");
>
> columns.Bound(p => p.BASE_AMOUNT_1).Title("Base Amount
> Debit").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "BASE_AMOUNT_1"
> }).ClientTemplate("#= TRANS_AMT_1 #"
> +"");
>
> columns.Bound(p => p.BASE_AMOUNT_1).Title("Base Amount
> Credit").ClientTemplate("#= TRANS_AMT_1 #" + "");
>
> columns.Bound(p =>
> p.DESCRIPTION).Title("Narration").ClientTemplate("#= DESCRIPTION #" +
> "");
>
> ```
>                     columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100);
>                     columns.Command(command => command.Edit()).Width(100);
>                 })
>                 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
>                 .Model(model =>
>                 {
>                     model.Id(p => p.TRANSROWID);
>                     model.Field(p => p.TRANSROWID).Editable(false);
>                     model.Field(p => p.ACCNT_CODE).Editable(true);
>                     model.Field(p => p.TRANS_AMT).Editable(true).DefaultValue(0);
>                     model.Field(p => p.TRANS_AMT_1).Editable(true).DefaultValue(0);
>                     model.Field(p => p.BASE_AMOUNT_1).Editable(true).DefaultValue(0);
>                     model.Field(p => p.DESCRIPTION).Editable(true).DefaultValue("");
>
>                 })
>                 .ServerOperation(false)
>                 .Batch(true)
>                 .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler")
>                 .Change("onChange"))
>                 
>                 )
>                 )
> ```

script:

> function onChange(e) {
>
> ```
>     var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
>         return $(item).text();
>     });
>     kendoConsole.log("Selected: " + selected.length + " item(s), [" + selected.join(", ") + "]");
> ```
>
> Error:
>
> Create:315 Uncaught Type Error: this.select is not a function
> at init.onChange (Create:315:35)
> at init.trigger (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at init._process (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at init.success (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at Object.success (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at init.read (kendo.aspnetmvc.js:1052:87)
> at kendo.all.js:309417:87
> at init._queueRequest (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at init.read (kendo.all.js:309417:87)
> at init.query (kendo.all.js:309417:87)

Comment: Can `error_handler` be called normally?

Answer (score 0):

According to [telerik's official documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/methods/select), the select method will not trigger the change event. Maybe this is the reason why `this.select` is not accepted. You can refer to the code in it.

Another possibility is that you need to select a value by default to correspond to the `this.select` function before letting the grid load.

Hope this can help you.